# Is there a way to prevent MonoDevelop updates from removing beta Mono libraries?

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I'm trying to use MonoDevelop 3.0.5 with the latest Mono .NET runtime (3.0.1). However, every time I apply an update to MonoDevelop it completely removes the new mono runtime from my system.

Is there a setting somewhere that will prevent MonoDevelop from removing newer framework versions?

Comment: that is clearly a bug, report it: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: @Russell would you be able to add a link to your bug report if you raised one? Cheers